# How can I update my rooted Moto G to 4.4.2

Tags: updates, rooting, 4.4-kitkat

Every time I try the OTA download it gives me an error while installing, which I presume is because I've rooted the phone.

It's a European model if it matters.

Comment: Yeah, rooting breaks OTA updates because you have to change `/system` to do it. The easiest thing to do is to flash the new ROM manually (instead of OTA), but I'm afraid I don't know the procedure for flashing Motorola phones. Maybe this advice will help you find the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to (re-) flash the complete (stock) ROM. Rooting involves changing things on the `/system` partition, which changes its [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum). Some OTA updates use the checksum to see whether the update "fits", and thus will refuse to install if not. Looks like your Moto falls into this category.

Answer (score -2):

you can unroot it by using framaroot before that put a superuser in your storage and then you can have the option of unrooting your phone,and the other way is use cyanogenmod

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with the first part. As for Cyanogenmod, would installing that not wipe all my data?

Comment: well just google it framroot it's an apk file which will help you to unroot your device,and for cyanogenmod use a titanium backup,after installing it will restore all your data

Comment: I see. It was the "put a superuser in your storage" I didn't get. Is that something I have to do myself before running framaroot?

Comment: yeah download a superuser.zip,and put it on your storage ..

Comment: Moto G isn't listed as a device supported by Framaroot

Comment: okay..So I hope you have to go to the xda forum there might you get some solution..

Comment: -1, this answer is nonsense. "Put a superuser in your storage" doesn't make any sense, and it's ridiculous to suggest the questioner use a custom ROM when an official update is available.

Comment: Thanks for the clear words, Dan! The whole thing looks weird. And especially for someone without experience, looks like just causing additional trouble.